# Find the invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $2$ matrices $A$, $B$ :

for example:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\ 
d & e & f\\ 
g & h & i
\end{pmatrix}$

$B=\begin{pmatrix}
a' & b' & c'\\ 
d' & e' & f'\\ 
g' & h' & i'
\end{pmatrix}$

I am requested to find an invertible matrix $P$, so that $B=PA$.

1. By definition $P$ is an invertible matrix, if there exists  $PP^{-1}=P^{-1}P=I$. Does it mean that $A=P^{-1}$ and $B=I$ ?
2. We have been taught to to find an inverse of a matrix using this method: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/mtrxinvr.htm. How is it possible to find $P$?

Comment: Are you given specific matrices $A$ and $B$? Are they related in some visible way? Are they invertible themselves?

Comment: Presuming $A$ and $B$ are invertible the matrix is trivially unique and $BA^{-1}$. If $A$ is not invertible then $\ker PA \neq 0$  so $B$ cannot be invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there exists such a matrix $P$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ have the same reduced row-echelon form.

Let $E$ denote this common row-echelon form matrix.  By the usual process of row-reduction ("Gaussian elimination"), we may find invertible matrices $R_1,R_2$ such that
$$
R_1A = R_2 B = E
$$
It would follow that $B = R_2^{-1}R_1A$.  That is, we may take $P = R_2^{-1}R_1$.